# Getting input variables from MySQL and sending output to Arduino

Tags: php, post, arduino, get

I'm saving sensor data to phpMyAdmin database and I want to use that data (the last entry) as input variables for a fuzzy function written in PHP.

Can I somehow send the output variable from fuzzy back to my Arduino? How would I configure the request on the board?

```
<?php
require_once ('./fuzzy-logic-class.php');

// Include data base connect class
$filepath = realpath (dirname(__FILE__));
require_once($filepath."/db_connect.php");

// Connecting to database 
$db = new DB_CONNECT();

// Actual Values
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT `temp`,`hum`,`moist` FROM `t_measure` ORDER BY id_measure desc LIMIT 1;");
$actual = $conn->query($sql);
if ($actual->num_rows > 0) {
// output data of each row
while($row = $actual->fetch_assoc()) {
    $acttemp = number_format($row["temp"],0);
    $acthum = number_format($row["humidity"],0);
    $actsoil = number_format($row["soil"],0);
}
} else {
echo "0 results";
}

/*----------------Fuzzy Parameters----*/
$x = new Fuzzy_Logic();
$x->clearMembers();
/* ---------- set input members ---------*/
$x->setInputNames(array('TEMP','HUMIDITY', 'SOIL'));
$x->addMember($x->getInputName(0),'COLD',  0,  8, 25   ,LINFINITY);
$x->addMember($x->getInputName(0),'WARM', 20, 35, 100  ,RINFINITY);
$x->addMember($x->getInputName(1),'LOW', 0  ,40 ,60    ,LINFINITY);
$x->addMember($x->getInputName(1),'HIGH',50 ,70 ,100   ,RINFINITY);
$x->addMember($x->getInputName(2),'WET', 0,   400 ,650  ,LINFINITY);
$x->addMember($x->getInputName(2),'DRY',550, 800 ,1025 ,RINFINITY);

/* ---------- set output members ---------*/
$x->setOutputNames(array('OUT'));
$x->addMember($x->getOutputName(0),'LOWER',-10, -5 ,0 ,LINFINITY);
$x->addMember($x->getOutputName(0),'RAISE',0, 5 ,10 ,RINFINITY);

/* ---------- set rule table ------------ */
$x->clearRules();
$x->addRule('IF TEMP.WARM OR SOIL.DRY OR HUMIDITY.LOW THEN OUT.RAISE');
$x->addRule('IF TEMP.COLD OR SOIL.WET OR HUMIDITY.HIGH THEN OUT.LOWER');


/*---------- Get values from database and calculate output ----*/
$x->SetRealInput('TEMP',    $acttemp);
$x->SetRealInput('HUMIDITY' ,$acthum);
$x->SetRealInput('SOIL' ,   $actsoil);
$fuzzy_arr = $x->calcFuzzy();
$Fuzzy = $fuzzy_arr['OUT'];
echo $Fuzzy;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it turns out I messed up combining two files. With this part corrected, the api works as it's supposed to.

```
       $servername = "---";
$username = "---";
$password = "---";
$dbname = "---";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
$Fuzzy = $_GET['val'];

// Actual Values
 $sql= "SELECT `temp`,`hum`,`moist` FROM `t_measure` ORDER BY id_measure desc LIMIT 1;";
$actual = $conn->query($sql);
```

To receive data on the Arduino side, this is the required code.

```
void setup() {

Serial.begin(115200);
WiFi.begin("ssid", "pass");   //WiFi connection
while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {  //Wait for the WiFI connection completion
delay(500);
Serial.println("Waiting for connection");

}

}

void loop() {

if(WiFi.status()== WL_CONNECTED){   //Check WiFi connection status
HTTPClient http;  
http.begin("http://.....");  //api location
http.addHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain"); 
String payload = http.getString(); //reading from api
Serial.println(payload);
http.end(); 
}else{
Serial.println("Error in WiFi connection");   

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using HTTP, it could be as simple as having a HTTPClient on your Arduino do a GET request to your server/phpfile, and reading the response. Examples abound on the interwebs; the library to use for this depends on the Arduino you use.

The response from your PHP should be something like:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n
Connection: close\n
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\n\n
[Your string in $Fuzzy]\n
```

If you want the server to take the initiative in sending the fuzzy value, things get a bit more complicated.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Can you tell me if there's anything I need to add to the PHP code or just on the Arduino side?

Comment: I would have the PHP output what I put in the answer instead of simply $Fuzzy; all the rest is done on the Arduino side using HTTPClient.

It may work without changing the PHP at all; it would then just respond with a string containing $Fuzzy. I have done things that way, but it isn't pretty and may not work in some cases.

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but I guess I'm too far behind to implement that. I'll try to get a grasp of the basics and then try this solution.